# How to apply style to treeviewitem if the datacontext is an object of Type T

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to create an IsSelectedProperty on the ViewModel and Bind to that instead?

I would like to be able to do something like Source={Binding RelativeAncestor ListViewItem}

but instead there is only this property sourcename which I can use to set triggers based off of the items in the datatemplate if I name them using x:Name

```
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger SourceName="" Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="bdr" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                  </Trigger>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Looking back, I realized that yesterday I made a very confusing post. Also, considering how hard I find it to even interpret people's comments to my questions, I should probably give more detail.

I know that in wpf you can set triggers based on the control by setting a style for the target control type.

In addition you also have data triggers that can trigger off of properties in the datacontext. What I was hoping was that there was a way to use triggers, or datatriggers to set a property when the datacontext is an object of a specific type.

is this possible? If not, I will just accept the provided answer as applicable in my situation, but since this will require me to add a property to my viewmodel, it seemed reasonable to check if there was a way to just check item type rather than having to check the actual property.

Comment: Have you tried using a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as that alows you to specify a binding like what you want? (Check the example XAML in the link I provided).

Comment: can datatriggers trigger off the type of the datacontext or only off properties on the datacontext? I was curious whether there was any way to create style triggers based on the type of the object set as the datacontext

Comment: For triggering off the *type* of the datacontext you would use DataTemplates (it looks like you already have) - any triggers in that template should only be evaluated if that template is used. Functionality based on type rather than value is also possible using a converter, but that's hackish. So in summary - for types use a template, for values use a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you bind the IsSelected property in your view model, but that's just me.

I'm not sure how complex your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is, or if some items need to have their Foreground changed, and some don't; but I'm going to assume you want to update the item that is selected throughout the entire TreeView (if that's what this is for).

If that is the case, just add `DataTrigger`s to the Style of the `TreeViewItem`:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected"
            Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}"
                     Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Black" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Note that you don't need to bind the `IsSelected` parameter if you don't want to, its just there because it's in my code.

Comment: I just realized you might want to be changing the property of the parent item.  Is that the case?

Comment: no, I know how to create triggers off properties of the item or the datacontext of the item, and you can set a style off the type of the control as well. But I was wondering if there was a method to set styles based on the type of the object that is set as the datacontext

Comment: Are you familiar with the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx)?